# NavigationPage for Android in Xamarin Forms

Tags: android, mvvm, xamarin, navigation, xamarin.forms

How can i use the Navigation Page for Android in Xamarin Form ?

I use this but it didn't work:

[image]

I want, when i press my button, to switch to my secondPage (DemoPage)
I don't know how i can do this.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

simply wrap your "main" page in a NavigationPage when you assign it in your App's constructor

```
public class App : Application
{
    public App ()
    {
        // The root page of your application
        MainPage = new NavigationPage(new MyMainPage());
    }
}
```

Comment: Work and use : await _navigation.PushAsync(new DemoPage());
Thank you